# google maps API (map not displaying)

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm confused.  I'm working with Google Maps API for the first time (version V3) and I don't understand why the Jquery onready shorthand isn't working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=set_to_true_or_false">
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions);
 }

</script>
```

I tried to both `$(function(){ }); and $(document).ready(function(){});`

My syntax was correct both times and firebug console showed no errors. Neither initializes the map.  However, when I added

`onload="initialize()` to my body tag, it worked.

Just curious what is happening here.

EDIT: HERE IS THE ACTUAL CODE

```
   <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">


  $(function(){
     function initialize() {
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
     var myOptions = {
     zoom: 8,
     center: latlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map")
    ,
     myOptions); 
 }
   });
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used that didn't work? Btw, you need to set `sensor` to either `true` or `false`

Comment: i don't think you are calling `initalize()` in previous two calls. onload should be `window.onload=initialize;`

Comment: Yeah, i think that you're right.  I define the function but don't call it here, huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your problem is 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=set_to_true_or_false">`
Did you set it to true or false?
BTW, did you link to a valid jQuery js sheet?
Do you have a proper `<Doctype>`?

Comment: my bad on the GET parameter.  In my code, I did in fact set sensor to false and JQuery works otherwise through my code

Comment: Wait, so did your problem get solved or still is stuck? BTW, make sure the jQuery library is connected before loading your custom JS.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this was fairly obvious.

I was defining initialize but not calling it.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, and your answer saved me some serious time!